# Improve Regular Expression for HTML-Tagname-strip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

Below is some string, which should be serve as my HTML-Code.
I am trying from below string or HTML-Code separate the HTML-Tagname. After processing on the string the result should be something like as follows: `=div=div=strong=em=p=b=p=p=h4=h1=span=`.
Here is my HTML-Code in the variable "sTagName":

```
var sTagName = 'abc<div style="left:100px;" > some <div>MyText, <strong> hgz uz <em> Some text for flrdm <p><b>b,  <p> <p><h4><h1><span id="MySpan">any text, ';
```

Here is my solution:

```
// Remove all attributes, e.g. <div style="left:100px;" > will be converted to <div>
sTagName = sTagName.replace(/<([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*?>.*?/g, '<$1>' );
// I add the "<>" at end of HTML-Code in order to remove the last useless string, I mean "Any text, "
sTagName = sTagName + "<>";
sTagName = sTagName.replace(/.*?<(.*?)>.*?/g,'=$1');

alert(sTagName);
```

The function `alert(sTagName)` delivers the expected result.
But I want improve my method referring to performance. E.g. I would like to build from two RegEx one RegEx, or something like that.
Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Wrong! I am not looking for a solution. But I want to improve my solution. I already read this link and with means of it written my current solution. As I written, I am trying to improve my methode.

Comment: Code improvements should be posted on [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Oh my goodness! I hate to get minus points. Therefore, I have long ago declared.:-( In addition, the link there contains among other Perl-RegEx-Code and is no longer clear.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use DOM:

```js
var sTagName = 'abc<div style="left:100px;" > some <div>MyText, <strong> hgz uz <em> Some text for flrdm <p><b>b,  <p> <p><h4><h1><span id="MySpan">any text, ';


tags = $("<div>").html(sTagName).find("*").map(function() {
  return this.nodeName;
}).toArray();

document.write(tags);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've tried before. But unfortunately DOM under certain circumstances gives me double tagNamea and the order of tagNames is not as I expected. So I try with RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
var sTagName = 'abc<div style="left:100px;" > some <div>MyText, <strong> hgz uz <em> Some text for flrdm <p><b>b,  <p> <p><h4><h1><span id="MySpan">any text, ';

var arr = new Array;
var result;
var re = /<(\w+)/g;

while ((m = re.exec(sTagName)) !==null) {
    arr.push(m[1]);
}

result = '=' + arr.join('=') + '=';

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sTagName = $.map(sTagName.split(/[^<\w+]/), function(v, k) {
  return /</.test(v) ? v.replace(/[a-z]+<|</g, "=") : null
}).join("").concat("=");
```

```js
var sTagName = 'abc<div style="left:100px;" > some <div>MyText, <strong> hgz uz <em> Some text for flrdm <p><b>b,  <p> <p><h4><h1><span id="MySpan">any text, ';

sTagName = $.map(sTagName.split(/[^<\w+]/), function(v, k) {
  return /</.test(v) ? v.replace(/[a-z]+<|</g, "=") : null
}).join("").concat("=");

$("body").text(sTagName)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<(\w+)\s*[^>]*>|.(?=([^><]*<[^>]*>)*[^<>]*$)
```

Try this.Replace by `$1`.Later on append `=` to each result.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qZ0uP0/2

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is what I was looking for :). This improves my previous solution.